# PhoneGap push plugin get data when app is in background?

Tags: android, cordova, firebase, ionic-framework, firebase-notifications

**Solution:**

The problem seems to be with messages sent by Firebase Test Console but I don't know why, yet. I started to send messages by using node-gcm and everything is working as expected from the beginning.

Both messages sent to a single device by device token. Messages in logcat:

- Sent from Firebase Test Console (Not working from bg):

`01-06 14:36:06.618 19422 19422 I chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(95702)] "{"sound":"default","title":"├üFA fizet├ęs 2016.11.30-a","message":"K├Âvetkez┼Ĺ esed├ękes k├Âtelezetts├ęg: ├üFA fizet├ęs 2016.11.30-a","additionalData":{"id":"1","google.message_id":"0:1483709767111210%********","coldstart":false,"collapse_key":"********","foreground":true}}", source: file:///android_asset/www/build/main.js (95702)`

- Sent by node-gcm script (Working even from bg):

`01-06 14:37:41.037 19422 19422 I chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(95702)] "{"title":"├üFA fizet├ęs 2016.11.30-a","message":"K├Âvetkez┼Ĺ esed├ękes k├Âtelezetts├ęg: ├üFA fizet├ęs 2016.11.30-a","additionalData":{"id":"1","google.message_id":"0:1483709856368443%*********","coldstart":false,"collapse_key":"do_not_collapse","foreground":false}}", source: file:///android_asset/www/build/main.js (95702)`

The difference I see is the collapse_key property, which contains the apk name of the application and the sound. Could this be caused by collapse_key?

**Updated shortened version:**

- Device registration is successful.
- Test notifications sent from Firebase Test Console.
- They arrive to the device:

  - When app is in the foreground, notification event is fired as it should be. OK
  - When app is in the background, the message appears on the notification bar of the os. If I click on it, my app gets activated and that's all. The notification event has not been called this way. NOT OK

**Original question:**

I'm using phonegap-push-plugin and I can not get the notification event fired when the app is in the background and clicking on the notify event on Android.

If the app is active, I can see that the event called on logcat. However if it is in the background and I click on the event notification, the app gets activated and nothing else happens according to logcat events. I have tried adding `content-available: 1` as an additional parameter in the Firebase test console, but that didn't help either.

Here is a row from logcat that shows up when the app is active:

```
01-05 22:41:59.981  9076  9186 V PushPlugin: extrasToJSON:
{"sound":"default","title":"Msg title","message":"Msg
body","additionalData":
{"id":"1","google.message_id":"0:1483652521531127%d86d9************",
"coldstart":false,"collapse_key":"************","foreground":true}}
```

The code is the same as everywhere else, I have immediate console.logs after the callback has been fired:

```
push.on('notification', (data) => {
    console.log('onNotification'); // not shown when app is in bg
```

Comment: please try from here .  https://github.com/santoshshinde2012/PushNotificationSample

Comment: @SantoshShinde I've followed many tutorials before including devgirls' and I can register, send and catch messages. The only problem is that while the app is in the background, the callback is not fired when clicking on the notification.

Answer (score 0):

Push plugin send notification when it is in background.
There is an event defined in Plugin documentation which fired by notification received , Try to catch the event and send notification using [Local Notification](https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-local-notifications) plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Please change your attributes for initialize the notification plugin using following way

```
        var push = PushNotification.init({
            android: {
                senderID: "12345679",
                forceShow : true
            },
            browser: {
                pushServiceURL: 'http://push.api.phonegap.com/v1/push'
            },
            ios: {
                alert: "true",
                badge: "true",
                sound: "true"
            },
            windows: {}
        });
```

`android.forceShow` its Controls the behavior of the notification when app is in foreground.

If `true` and app is in foreground, it will show a notification in the notification drawer, the same way as when the app is in background (and on`('notification')` callback will be called only when the user clicks the notification). When `false` and app is in foreground, the on`('notification')` callback will be called immediately.

For more details look into plugin documentation from [here](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-push/blob/master/docs/API.md)..

Also please look into the issue from [here](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-push/issues/1506)...

Hopes this will help you !!!